# Callback service on the website using Twilio

Tags: webrtc, twilio, sip, voip

Let's say I need to implement a callback service on a website.
I'm curious if it's possible to develop it using Twilio.

For example, if a website visitor provides his mobile phone number from one side, from another side I have a manager using his web CRM application. Is it possible to:

1. Make a call (using WebRTC?) to a manager
2. When the manager replies the incoming call, call to the website visitor (on his mobile phone)
3. Connect both sides together

I know there are lots of ready-to-use callback services, I'm just curious how it works under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is a feature we call Click to Call. Here's how it would work with Twilio:

1. The visitor provides his number through a form on the site
2. [Generate a call to the manager using the Twilio REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls)
3. When the call connects to the manager, dial the visitor.

   - This is achieved using [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml)
   - Whent the call connects, Twilio makes an HTTP request to a URL you provide in step 2
   - That URL needs to respond with TwiML, which is a subset of XML to tell Twilio what to do with the call
   - In this case the TwiML would be to [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) the visitors number
4. When the visitor answers the two are connected

This is a high level view of it, we also have a [tutorial walking you through Click to Call with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/click-to-call/python/flask) (this is the Python version, but there are others available too) which I recommend you take a look at.

Let me know if this helps at all.