# Connect 2 persons using Twilio's Elastic SIP Trunking

Tags: twilio, sip, voip

I have a situation where I need to connect 2 persons together using Twilio Elastic SIP Trunking.

So, I have two mobile phone numbers, I need to call first person and when he answer an incoming call, I need to call second person and when he answer an incoming call, connect them together.

Those 2 persons could be in different countries. So, is it possible to use Twilio's Elastic SIP Trunking to accomplish this purpose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Callback service on the website using Twilio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232238/callback-service-on-the-website-using-twilio)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe this is a follow on from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41232238/callback-service-on-the-website-using-twilio). I recommend you read my answer there.

If you have two people with separate phones, then you are not looking to use Elastic SIP Trunking. That feature is for when you have a PBX and SIP phones and you are looking to connect them to the PSTN.